# Integration of two dimensional dirac delta

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I want to integrate the two dimensional dirac delta function:
$
\delta^2(x,y)=\delta(x)\delta(y)
$

I know that for the one dimensional case the integral is
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)dx = 1$ so it should be also 1 for the two dimensional case?

Comment: Short version: If the point (0,0) is inside the 2D integration domain, yes!

Comment: Doesn't the bounds from -inf to +inf implicate that the point(0,0) is inside the integration domain? So I am looking for the indefinite integral. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, obviously, but you would need two separate integrals for the 2D integration. Since you did not specify these, I did not want to assume anything on the integration domain.

Comment: Maybe I should reframe my question to ask for the indefinite integral.

Comment: **hint:** Multiplication of distributions is not defined. (But convolution is.)

Comment: @mathreadler To be medium picky, convolution is not defined for two arbitrary distributions without an extra condition on their supports. If $\delta(f(x, y)) \delta(g(x, y))$ is taken to mean a distribution on a hypersurface, it is well-defined, provided that certain conditions on $f$ and $g$ hold.

Comment: @Maxim Under what conditions can you not define it as convolved after each other in sequence on a test function? Is there some easy to explain example to show where it doesn't work?

Comment: @mathreadler We want to define $(f*g, \phi) = (f, x \mapsto (g, y \mapsto \phi(x + y)))$ (the direct product $f \times g$ applied to $\phi(x + y)$), but $x \mapsto (g, y \mapsto \phi(x + y))$ is not necessarily in the space of test functions anymore. We have to take a restriction of $\phi(x + y)$ without changing its values on the support of $f \times g$. This is well-defined if the supports of $f$ and $g$ are bounded on the same side. $H*H$ is fine, but $H*1$ is not.

Comment: @mathreadler I should clarify that this is for two functionals with unbounded supports. If either $f$ or $g$ has finite support, $f*g$ is always defined.

Comment: It is always good to be thorough! Good good.